# "Limit form" of non-autonomous linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let us consider ODE
$$
f^{(n)} + a_{n-1}(t) f^{(n-1)} + \ldots + a_1(t) f + a_0(t) = 0
$$
with smooth coefficients s.t. $a_i(t) \to b_i \in \mathbb R$ when $t \to +\infty$.

Is it true that fundamental solutions of the initial equation tend to solutions of "limit equation" with constant coefficients?
$$
f^{(n)} + b_{n-1} f^{(n-1)} + \ldots + b_1 f + b_0 = 0.
$$

I.e. for any solution $f$ of the first equation there exists solution $\tilde f$ of the second equation such that $|f(t) - \tilde f(t)| \to 0$ when $t \to +\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not true.

Consider $n = 1$, $a_0(t) = -\frac{1}{1+t}$. Then $a_0(t) \to 0 =: b_0$ for $t \to \infty$,
$$
f(t) = \ln(1+t)
$$
is a fundamental solution to the first ODE and all solutions of the second ODE are of the form
$$
\tilde f(t) = C \quad \text{for some $C \in \mathbb R$},
$$
hence $|f(t) - \tilde f(t)| \not\to 0$ for $t \to \infty$ for all these $\tilde f$.

Comment: Nice counterexample! Whether there are some sufficient conditions when the statement is true?

Comment: @vanger: Maybe, but I don‘t know any. (That is, I don‘t know anything more meaningful than “the statement is true if it is true“.)